# Запуск консольного приложения в фоновом режиме

Tags: windows

Мне нужно, чтобы следы приложения не всплывали нигде. То есть, чтобы его не было видно на "панели задач", в трее и в "диспетчере задач". И разумеется полное отсутствие окон.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то за написание вируса можно получить уголовное преследование::)

Comment: Политика этого ресурса - чёткий ответ на вопрос. Что-то  я не вижу ответа, трёп один

Comment: Не надо думать, что в вопросе есть что-то оригинальное. Только вчера был аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса противоречит самому вопросу. Консоль - окно которое видно для диалога с пользователем, а не скрывается во дворах.

Comment: чисто формально - консоль скрыть легко, из панели само скроется, если нету окна. А вот из диспетчера убрать - никак.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну почему сразу вирусы? Может быть он службы имеет в виду, только не знает, как это называется.

Comment: @Arhad, _следы приложения не всплывали нигде_ - сервисы не подходят, они же в списке сервисов, отображаются

Comment: @Grundy, судя по стилю оформления вопроса, могу предположить, что его автор дальше вкладок «Приложения», «Процессы» и «Быстродействие» не заглядывал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно полное отсутствие взаимодействия с пользователем — напишите [службу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B_Windows) (аналог под Linux — демон). Службы не привязаны к конкретным пользовательским сессиям, они работают в фоне, даже если вход в систему не выполнен.

Только учтите, что даже служба может быть остановлена через  <kbd>Панель управления → Администрирование → Службы</kbd> силами административной учётной записи. Этому никак противостоять нельзя, поскольку владелец компьютера должен обладать полным контролем над своим ПК.